# Wives and daughters and the Mitzvos of Purim

Tags: purim, women, mishloach-manot, tzedakah-charity

Can a married woman rely on her husband for the mitzvos of Purim of Shalach Manos and Mattanos Levyonim (I recall  somthing about Ishto Kigufo)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Rama* (the *Mapa*) 695:4 says (all translations are my own, and you shouldn't rely on their accuracy):

> And a woman is obligated in *matanos laevyonim* (gifts to paupers) and *mishloach manos* (the sending of foods) like a man, and a woman should send to a woman and a man to a man but not vice versa so that he not come to send to a widow and they come under a *safek kidushin* (inclarity about whether there is *kidushin* (marriage)), but by *matanos laevyonim* one need not worry.

*Mishna B'rura* comments:

> *"And a woman is obligated", etc.:* [...] And *Magen Avraham* wrote:
>
> > I haven't seen people careful about this; perhaps it's only for a widow, whereas the husband of a married woman sends on her behalf to a number of men. In any event, one should be stringent.

(Examination of the *MA* shows that his headword is "And a woman is obligated". Also that he wrote "a number of people" where *MB* quoted him as having written "a number of men".)

*P'ri M'gadim* explains the *MA*:

> ... and when she's married, the authority (*r'shus*) of her husband is upon her; and a widow and virgin are obligated.

Make of all that what you will, and, of course, [CYLOR](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/CYLOR) for a practical ruling.

Comment: Chayei Adam writes similarly: "the married women here are accustomed to assuming that their husbands will send on their behalf; this is incorrect, and she should send her own."

Comment: Which raises the question: If _maase yadeha_ are her husband's, what is she sending?

Comment: @msh210, if necessary she could say "can I have this fruit basket unconditionally, for any use I want" (al menas sh'ein lo reshus), if he agrees, then it's totally hers. Practically the financial arrangement of most normal couples in 21st century America is such that she can buy and gift a couple of hamentashen or apples without asking her husband! (The enactment that he receive her minor income was the standard suggested when he's out-earning and supporting her, but a couple can agree on any arrangement they prefer, including complete financial independence.)

Answer (score 0):

The Kitzur Shulchan Aruch siman 142:4 writes that some women rely on their husbands to give mishaloach manos on their behalf, and he writes that its not correct and one should be machmir.

Rav Shlomo Zalman Auerbach V'alehu Lo Yibul 1:437 held not like this kitzur ,but held that one mishlaoch manos is sufficient for both .